# How to select rows on right click in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

This might be a rather simple question to answer.

I'm using Ag-Grid with React (ag-grid community + enterprise)

I noticed that if I right click on a row and I select an action on the context menu that appears, it will apply the action to the row that was *actually* selected and not the one I right-clicked on. How can I select a row with a right-click?

I will add details of my code on demand if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook in [cellContextMenu](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection-cellContextMenu) grid event and select the corresponding row as the first thing before proceeding to the rest of the logic. Something like this:

```
<AgGridReact onCellContextMenu={event => event.node.setSelected()}>
```